# Trying to pass js variables to php with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

As the title says, I'm trying to pass a couple js variables to a php file. Here is my code so far.

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "sendDataToDB.php",
    data: {
        mainVideoData: mainVideoTitle
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert("data sent");
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert("Data sending failed");
    }
});
```

sendDataToDB.PHP:

```
<?php
$temp = $_POST["mainVideoData"];
echo $temp;
?>
```

I saw this code on different websites, but for some reason it's not working for me. It says that `'mainVideoData'` is `undefined` which basically means that it doesn't exist.

Does anyone know what I did wrong?
Thanks!

EDIT:

I've read some suggestions, and decided to make a whole new file with just the code someone gave me that worked for him. Here is my whole php file and whole js file.

php.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="getApiData.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=""/>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['mainVideoData'])){
    $temp = $_POST["mainVideoData"];
    echo $temp;
}
?>
```

And here is my whole js file:

```
$(document).ready ( function(){
    var mainVideoTitle = "Hello";
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "php.php",
        data: {
            mainVideoData: mainVideoTitle
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert("data sent");
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert("Data sending failed");
        }
    });
});
```

It only gives me an alert saying 'data sent', but it doesn't echo 'hello'.
Does anyone know what's wrong?

EDIT 2:

So I've added some code in my php file that should put my $temp in a database. Sadly that doesn't work. When I replace $temp by a normal value like 'hello' it places it in my database. When I use $temp it gives me this error:

Error: INSERT INTO youtubevideos (category)
 VALUES (Wiz Khalifa - See You Again ft. Charlie Puth [Official Video] Furious 7 Soundtrack)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Khalifa - See You Again ft. Charlie Puth [Official Video] Furious 7 Soundtrack)' at line 2

As you can see, it does give me the right value, and it also places that right value in VALUES. But for some reason it still gives me this error. Any reason why?

Comment: try `data:{mainVideoData: "mainVideoTitle"}`

Comment: Where are you defining `mainVideoTitle`?

Comment: mainVideoTitle is a variable I made previously

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Comment: yes, i did include jquery

Comment: You need to make sure that `mainVideoTitle` is accessible to the ajax.

Comment: If you put quotes around `mainVideoTitle`, does `$_POST['mainVideoData'] = 'mainVideoTitle'`?

Comment: It is accessible to the ajax

Comment: I've just tried that, Alex, and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Why would it say "hello" anywhere?  You've sent that as a response to the AJAX call but not actually done anything with it.  Change the success function to `alert(data);` and see what it says.

Comment: While passing the ajax what error you get after using your edited code?

Comment: mainVideoTitle has 'hello' in it. I'm supposed to send mainVideoTitle to my .php file and then echo it

Comment: That is exactly what is happening.  The `echo` is returned in `data` that is sent to the success function.

Comment: Really? But why does it also give me my whole html code when I echo data?

Comment: Look at your file `php.php`  It is returning exactly what is in that file.  Strip out the html and you won't get it sent back.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. jQuery library is definitely included
> 2. check the path of your `php file` is valid
> 3. check `mainVideoTitle` defined or not

After just try this.

**script:**

```
 $(document).ready ( function(){
   var mainVideoTitle = "Hello";
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "sendDataToDB.PHP",
        data: {
            mainVideoData: mainVideoTitle
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert("data sent");
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert("Data sending failed");
        }
    });
```

});

**sendDataToDB.PHP:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['mainVideoData'])){
$temp = $_POST["mainVideoData"];
echo $temp;
}
?>
```

I hope this is help to achieve your result!!!

Comment: 1. jquery library is definitely included. 2. hmm, how exactly do I check that? 3. mainVideoTitle is defined. I've tried your code, and it still doesn't recognize mainVideoData

Comment: My self its working perfectly!, its returned the string 'hello' and alerted 'data sent'.

Comment: It only says 'data sent' for me. It does not return the string 'hello' for some reason.

Comment: do you want to alert the string 'hello' as success data?

Comment: Look at the edit that I've placed. I've placed your code in a whole new file and it still doesn't echo 'hello'. What is the difference between my file and your file?

Comment: use this, `success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            },`

Comment: It's giving me an alert with all my html codeinside it, and below that it says 'hello'

Comment: finally try this `success: function(data) {
                $('body').text(data);
            },`

Comment: It's given me this:  <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="jquery-2.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="getApiData.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href=""/>
 </head>
 <body>
 
 </body>
 </html>
 
 Hello

Comment: But can you tell me what the exact difference is between what you tried with your code and my code that I posted in my edit?

Comment: as per your edit the data send to `php.php` and alerted the string `data sent` and I suggests you via comment for get the echoed string will alerted and append (for your reference of data was send and return)

Comment: I've added another edit and I really have no idea why it's doing this. Do you maybe know why?

Comment: I cleared your first edit so you make a new question for that third edit. and also your third edit is not clear! where is your sql query? what is the value of  `mainVideoTitle`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work.Data will be captured in success.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "sendDataToDB.php",
    data: {
        mainVideoData: mainVideoTitle
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert("data sent");
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert("Data sending failed");
    }
});
```